# Split Rows on excel based on / in a field

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, vba

Assume Column B has data such as Data1/Data2/Data3-1/Data3-7 - all other rows have various data.

I need to take each row that has that Column B (some may not) and create 1 row for each individual value, with every other piece of data in the row copied for all of them.

Data may have symbols, dashes, and other random stuff, but the actual data itself will not have a / in it, only / is used to designate split lines

Any1 know the best way to do this? Excel 07 and OO available.

Comment: did forget to mention, the data column with slashes does have variable amounts of data in it, such as 2, 3, or 4 /'s total.

Comment: How good is your VBA? This can be accomplished through VBA with a a little more than a minimal amount of effort. Otherwise, I think your left to manually doing it for each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a VBA solution OK?

```
Sub DuplicateRows()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)

    Do While r.Row > 1
        TestRow r
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
    TestRow r


End Sub

Sub TestRow(r As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim a() As String

    i = InStr(r, "/")
    If i > 0 Then
        n = Len(r) - Len(Replace(r, "/", ""))
        r.EntireRow.Copy
        r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(n).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        a = Split(r, "/")
        For i = 0 To n
            r.Offset(i, 0) = a(i)
        Next
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```